# How to solve concurrency Insert issue in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes `@id` as input parameter. Table `Student` has primary key on `Id_Column` and `Count_Column`. If any record is present in table for the given `id`, then I select the max `Count_Column` from table and insert new row by incrementing max `Count_Column` by 1 else with zero value.

I'm calling this stored procedure from ado.net code in a WCF service and this service is called from an asp.net web application.

This stored procedure works fine in normal cases, but when multiple users calls it at same time, primary key violation issue happen, same case I have reproduced by making application multithreaded too. I know that this issue is related to concurrency, initially I was using `with(nolock)` in select query, but I have removed this now.

Somewhere I have read that by setting transaction isolation level it can be solved but when I tried I am some getting rollback transaction exception.

Please let me know any efficient solution for this problem.

```
declare @iCount = 0;

if exists(select 'x' from Student with(nolock) where Id_Column = @iId)
begin
    set @iCount = (select max(Count_Column) 
                   from Student
                   where Id_Column = @iId)
end

insert into Student
values(@id, @iCount + 1);
```

2nd solution:

```
begin try
set transaction isolation level serializable
begin transaction
    declare @iCount = 0;

    if exists(select 'x' from from Student with(nolock) where Id_Column = @iId)
    begin
        set @iCount = (select max(Count_Column) 
                       from Student
                       where Id_Column = @iId)
    end

    insert into Student
    values(@id, @iCount + 1);

    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction
end catch
```

Comment: have you heard of `Auto Incremented fields`

Comment: You could look into using [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx).

Comment: have you read my question properly? @MethodMan

Comment: this is what SQL Server has / allows for setting up a column for auto-increment this way when you do your Insert you make sure that the Id field is the primary key with auto-increment and proper seeing set if necessary, then when calling the insert you insert everything that you need except the Id field because it will be auto generated.. also read some tutorials on basic query's and setting up auto increment fields in sql server

Comment: Dude take a break and read

Comment: I most certainly have read your question properly and it shouldn't matter if 2 different interfaces are using / updating the same table.. I do this all the time from a web service, windows service, web application and concurrent win forms app..

Comment: @MethodMan I don't think an auto incremented field would work as the OP is not incrementing the `Count` column for every row, but by rows with the same `Id`.  Of course there might be a table redesign that would make more sense, but there's not enough here to determine that.

Comment: Have you tried the combination of UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK for the select instead of NOLOCK?

Comment: @juharr U r right, I have taken simple example here just to tell my issue.

Comment: You could keep people from running the stored procedure at the same time like this:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3202/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-the-same-sql-server-stored-procedure-at-the-same-time/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like......

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     DECLARE @iCount INT;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Student WITH(UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) WHERE Id_Column = @iId)
    BEGIN

      select @iCount = ISNULL(max(Count_Column), 0) + 1 
      from Student WITH(UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) where Id_Column = @iId

         insert into Student
         values(@id, @iCount);
    END
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

 IF (@@TRANCOUNT <> 0)
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END CATCH
```

**Important Note**

You should really be using `Identity` column here to handle the auto-increment value. If you are using sql server 2012 or later you also have another option of using `Sequence Object` also an auto-increment .

Comment: doing `UPDLOCK` with a `HOLDLOCK` is pointless. HOLDLOCK is much more restrictive ([it is equvilant to the `SERIALIZABLE` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)) and overwrites the UPDLOCK hint.

Answer (score 0):

There is a failsafe strategy: `SERIALIZABLE` isolation and retry in case of deadlock. The definition of `SERIALIZABLE` is as-if-serial execution which excludes all race conditions.

I don't know why you are catching exceptions there. All that accomplishes is suppress errors.

Comment: Whenever you have a transaction you have the possibility of the transaction failing (it will fail gracefully but it can and in production occasionally fail) and when it does it leaves and a transaction in a half dead state (un-committable but still somewhat alive) so in that case its good practice to put it out of its misery.

Comment: If you don't commit a transaction explicitly it is always rolls back. This is typically the case when the app cleans up resources (in other words 1ms later). It is a waste of dev time to wrap each sql batch in defensive behavior. In this case it resulted in a bug: The error is swallowed and the app continues running oblivious to the fact that this operation has failed and that there is no tran. The app will now spam harmful statements to the database outside of a tran.

Comment: The example can add a throw to further notify that an error occurred. Of course a transaction that is not committed  is rolled back but by issuing an explicit 'rollback' the memory and objects that SQL Server uses to maintain the transaction is immediately released.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has sequences and MS followed with Sql Server 2012 with their implementation calling it sequence objects which is not table specific.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE   
Schema.MySequence
AS int
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

You can then use it as follow:

```
DECLARE @iCount int ;
SET @iCount = NEXT VALUE 
FOR Schema.MySequence;
```

This is similar as the nextval in Oracle and will ensure uniqueness. The only question is if you will accept gaps in your count sequence in the case of rolledback/failed transactions or not...