# Web API async method called two times

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I am stuck in finding the cause why the code is internally called twice and saving duplicate records in database with milliseconds of time. The time difference between two records was:

EntryDateTime
2017-03-21 08:17:11.957 (Record 1)
2017-03-21 08:17:11.960 (Record 2)

Here is the code. For simplicity, I have removed the debugging lines and validation logic to make it more clear.

```
// Controller
[Route("CreateUser")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCreateUser(SignUp parameters)
{
    try
    {
            SignUpRepository repo = new SignUpRepository();
    var response = await repo.ResisterUser(parameters);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok("Error occurred...." + ex.Message);
    }

    return Ok("SignUp successfully completed.");

}

// SignUpRepository Class
public async Task<String> ResisterUser(SignUp signUp) 
{

    SignUpManager manager = new SignUpManager();
    var createUser = await CreateUserAsync(signUp, manager);

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(createUser)) {
        return "No user created";
    }

    return "User successfully created.";
}

private Task<string> CreateUserAsync(SignUp signUp, SignUpManager manager)
{
    return Task.Run<string>(() => CreateUserAccount(signUp, manager));
}

private string CreateUserAccount(SignUp signUp, SignUpManager manager)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer {
        User_Name = signUp.UserName,
        Password = signUp.Password,
        First_Name = signUp.FirstName,
        Last_Name = signUp.LastName,
        Email_Address = signUp.Email,
        Mobile_Number = signUp.Mobile,
        Country_Id = signUp.CountryId
    };
    return manager.RegisterUser(customer);
}

// SignUpManager Class
public string RegisterUser(Customer customer)
{
    return new SQLHelper().RegisterUser(customer);
}

// SQL Helper Class
public string RegisterUser(Customer customer)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String value"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            // cmd.CommandText = "sp_RegisterUserByThirdParty";
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_RegisterUserByLEOSmart";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", customer.User_Name));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", customer.Password));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Full_Name", String.Format("{0} {1}", customer.First_Name, customer.Last_Name)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mobile_Number", customer.Mobile_Number));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", customer.Email_Address));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Country_ID", customer.Country_Id));

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@outToken", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16));
            cmd.Parameters["@outToken"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.response = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@outToken"].Value);
        }
    }
    return this.response;
}
```

There are some validation check in stored procedure itself but strangely all are bypass and record saved.

Can anyone help me out why it was happening?

Thanks

Comment: Did you debug in which place code executed twice? Is it possible that `PostCreateUser` handle 2 requests with simular data? I.e. user hit button twice or your client code send 2 post requests

Comment: Most likely the client called twice. Check there first

Comment: I've never used Task.Run, but should it be awaited?

Comment: I don't think that client code send 2 post requests. If client even send 2 post requests why the database validation checks did not run written in stored procedure for checking duplication before saving record. I am copying few on them over here: 

-- User Name                             
IF EXISTS (Select 1 from Customer where User_Name = @username)                              
RETURN '3' 

-- Mobile No                            
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customer WHERE Mobile_Number = @Mobile_Number) 
RETURN '2'

Comment: @AImran for database side you should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018342/how-to-solve-concurrency-insert-issue-in-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: Database side was given for highlighting the point that still in presence of validation checks duplicate records were saved as I am not sure it was concurrency issue.